# Ionic - iOS vs Android request

Tags: android, json, ionic-framework

A request that I know is safe and sound in iOS and Chrome (`ionic serve`), yet fails on the Android emulator and a droid device by jumping into the `error` bracket

```
    var requestURL = 'http://myURL/stuff/doStuff.php?a=' + encodeURIComponent(a)+ '&b=' + encodeURIComponent(b);

    $http.get(requestURL).success(function (results) {
        deferred.resolve(results);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(headers);
        deferred.reject(data);
    });
```

I checked through the debugger and the `requestURL` is fine.
The php sends a JSON header which is parsed by iOS and Chrome, so I do not quite get why it fails.

Edit:
I checked the server logs and the server is not getting any requests. It used to work, and I am not aware of any change to the android build settings that I would have made on purpose. iOS still does the job and I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

enabled.I think there must be something wrong with other permissions of the APK or something similar... Any idea where I could dig?

Comment: Fails with an error?

Comment: check for meta tags in HTML header part.

Comment: @cricket_007 If jumps into the error bracket of the request.

Comment: can you share with us more debugging info?, e.g. what is `data`, `status` or `headers`, stack traces...

Comment: Okay - then you should tell us what the messages in the console are saying

Comment: and your url is not something like localhost?

Comment: also, you need to look at those error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your android manifest.xml file have internet permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: yes, it's there... `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`